# Ext.ensible.cal.RecurrenceField not working on Ext.TabPanel

Tags: calendar, extjs4, sencha-touch, recurrence, recurring

I am new to `ExtJS` and I am working on a project that creates a recurrence when an appointment is scheduled.

After some digging, I got a link for creating recurrence like http://ext.ensible.com/deploy/dev/examples/form/recurrence-widget.html

I have to show this in `Ext.TabPanel` after some fields. I used the below code in item column, but the recurrence view is not included in the `panel`.

**Code:**

```
var recurField = Ext.createWidget('extensible.recurrencefield', {
    anchor: '90%',
    listeners: {
        'change': function (field, value) {
            Ext.get('recur-value').update(field.getValue() || '(Empty string)');
            Ext.get('recur-desc').update(field.getDescription() || '(Empty string)');
        }
    },
    frequencyWidth: 181
});
```

I tried including `Ext.ensible.ical.RecurrenceField` in my project, but I am getting an error `name is undefined`.

Am I missing something?

Please guide me in the right way...

Comment: Please provide a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor) for what you have tried so far.

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ic1 i tried like this

Comment: The [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ic1), you provide is having errors.

Comment: BTW, where is your `recur-panel` and `recur-dt` as you are using `renderTo`?

Comment: updated to Ext.getbody()

Comment: Check this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ic3)

Comment: this fiddle working, but could you explain me to add which file to my project to access the RecurrenceField widget,

Comment: I have added block comment as "Extensible 1.6.1 Start" and "Extensible 1.6.1 End" in the fiddle for that.